# Storing dictionary of dictionaries in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store a dictionary which contains two dictionaries in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *defDict = [def dictionaryRepresentation];

defaultTopics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Animals",
                                                    @"Numbers",
                                                    @"AroundTown",
                                                    @"Actions", nil];
defaultValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1, @0, @0, @0, nil];

NSDictionary *dd = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:defaultValues forKeys:defaultTopics];

NSDictionary *de = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[dd, dd] forKeys:@[@"English", @"Indonesian"]];

[defDict setValue:de forKey:@"UnlockedTopics"];
[def synchronize];
```

After this, `NSLog(@"%@", [def dictionaryRepresentation]);`, prints the correct dictionary, as long as I don't quit the app everything is as expected. But then, if I quit the app and relaunch,

```
[defDict objectForKey:@"UnlockedTopics"]
```

is always nil. What is the reason, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The reason the dictionary of dictionaries is not getting stored is that you are never storing it. All you're doing is setting the key of a dictionary. You are calling

```
[defDict setValue:de forKey:@"UnlockedTopics"];
```

But that is not the same thing as setting any `@"UnlockedTopics"` key-value pair *in NSUserDefaults*. If you want to write to NSUserDefaults, write to it - e.g. by sending `setObject:forKey:` *to NSUserDefaults*.

Comment: Alright, that was just a typo which you could simply mention, defDict should be def. You didn't need to be so rude.

Comment: Hey, all I have to go on is your code. Like your computer, I don't know what you _mean_. I know only what you _say_.

Comment: Still you don't need to be rude.

Comment: No rudeness intended. The code is not working. Now why would that be? The computer is not busted. So it would have to be because the code contains a mistake. You asked "What is the reason", I told you the reason. I can hardly do that without pointing out the mistake. If you can't look your mistakes in the face, don't post on Stack Overflow (and don't program, because mistakes are inevitable).

Comment: Moreover, your code does only one thing with `defDict` once you create it - it writes to it. Therefore it is perfectly reasonable to me to guess that you imagine that writing to it is going to be efficacious in some way. You really do appear to think that `dictionaryRepresentation` does something it doesn't do.

Comment: You removed the rudeness in your response and you are posting these comments after you edited it! I did other things with defDict later in the code.

Comment: I removed the phrase I thought you didn't like because I thought you asked me to. Are you asking me to put it back?

Comment: Regardless he has offended you @matt has found your problem(s).  If all you are going to do is attack him then perhaps there is more rudeness than you perceive.